# Passing params to @BeforeClass and @AfterClass methods

Tags: java, testng

I am invoking TestNG programmaticaly. I use Data Providers to pass values to test method. Is there any way if I can pass a parameter to @BeforeClass and @AfterClass methods?

Answer (score 0):

You can try @Parameters for @BeforeMethod if that helps.

[TestNG JavaDocs for Parameters](http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/annotations/Parameters.html)

[TestNG Documentation for Parameters](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters)

Answer (score 0):

I was also looking for the same but I tried to pass parameters to `@BeforeMethod`, `@BeforeClass`, `@BeforeSuite` and `@Test` methods and observed that it works for all except `@BeforeClass` but when I tried with `@BeforeClass`, no error is thrown.

Instead of going for `@BeforeClass`, you can pass parameters to `@BeforeSuite` which might help you to achieve your goal.